# How many combinations of ten options?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If we have ten different options and we can have combinations of none, one, two and so on up to all ten of the options, how many possible combinations could we have?

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {10\choose{k}}$$if order does not matter

Answer (score 2):

For each integer $k$, $1\leq k \leq 10$, we can include the $k$th option ("yes"), or not include it ("no").

So there are ten yes/no decisions to make in all, with two possibilities for each option ( "yes" or "no").

This gives us $$\underbrace{2\times 2 \times \cdots \times 2}_{\large 10 \text{ factors}}=2^{10}$$ possible combinations, including the "empty" combination, in which no option is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the ten options is either in the combination  or out of it giving $2^{10}$ possibilities.